Codeigniter 4 - somehow each variable is NULL when $this->request->getPost() after jQuery AJAX call
For some reason I can't find the bug... The form's text fields are numbers but for some reason they have a value of NULL when sent to the Controller.
this is my view:
<div class="row">
                <h1>Mortgage Calculator</h1>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <!-- Form start -->
                    <form id="mortgageCalculatorForm" action="<?= base_url('mortgage-calculator/calculate'); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="loanAmount" class="form-label">Loan Amount ($)</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="loanAmount" name="loanAmount" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="interestRate" class="form-label">Interest Rate (%)</label>
                            <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="interestRate" name="interestRate" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="mb-3">
                            <label for="loanTerm" class="form-label">Loan Term (years)</label>
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="loanTerm" name="loanTerm" required>
                        </div>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Calculate</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <!-- Result output -->
                    <div class="mt-3" id="result">
                        <h4>Result</h4>
                        <p id="monthlyPayment"></p>
                        <p id="totalInterestPaid"></p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <!-- jQuery/Javascript to update form -->
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $('#mortgageCalculatorForm').on('submit', function(event) {
                            event.preventDefault();

                            const loanAmount = $('#loanAmount').val();
                            const interestRate = $('#interestRate').val();
                            const loanTerm = $('#loanTerm').val();
                            
                            $.ajax({
                                url: '<?= base_url("mortgage-calculator/calculate"); ?>', // Replace with your server endpoint
                                type: 'POST',
                                contentType: 'application/json',
                                data: JSON.stringify({
                                    loanAmount: loanAmount,
                                    interestRate: interestRate,
                                    loanTerm: loanTerm
                                }),
                                success: function(data) {
                                    $('#monthlyPayment').text(`Monthly Payment: $${data.monthlyPayment}`);
                                    $('#totalInterestPaid').text(`Total Interest Paid: $${data.totalInterestPaid}`);
                                },
                                error: function(error) {
                                    console.error('Error:', error);
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                </script>
            </div>

this is my controller:
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Controllers\BaseController;
use CodeIgniter\HTTP\ResponseInterface;

class MortgageCalculator extends BaseController
{
    // AJAX call to this function, returns JSON data.
    public function calculate()
    {
        // Get form data
        $loanAmount = $this->request->getPost('loanAmount');
        $interestRate = $this->request->getPost('interestRate');
        $durationYears = $this->request->getPost('loanTerm');
        
        
        var_dump($loanAmount);


        // API endpoint URL
        $apiUrl = 'https://api.api-ninjas.com/v1/mortgagecalculator?loan_amount=' . $loanAmount . '&interest_rate=' . $interestRate . '&duration_years=' . $durationYears;

        // Your API key
        $apiKey = $_SERVER['api.API_Ninjas'];

        // Initialize cURL session
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set cURL options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $apiUrl);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'X-Api-Key: ' . $apiKey
        ));

        // Execute the request
        $response = curl_exec($ch);

        // Check for cURL errors
        if ($response === false) {
            $error = curl_error($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $this->response->setJSON([
                'error' => true,
                'message' => 'Error: ' . $error
            ]);
        }

        // Close the cURL session
        curl_close($ch);

        // Decode the JSON response
        $data = json_decode($response, true);

        // Check if the API response contains the expected data
        if (isset($data['monthly_payment']['mortgage']) && isset($data['total_interest_paid']))
        {
            // Prepare the response data
            $responseData = [
                'monthlyPayment' => $data['monthly_payment']['mortgage'],
                'totalInterestPaid' => $data['total_interest_paid']
            ];

            // Return the response data as JSON
            return $this->response->setJSON($responseData);
        }
        else
        {
            // Return an error if the API response is not as expected
            return $this->response->setJSON([
                'error' => true,
                'message' => 'Invalid API response'
            ]);
        }
    }
}


I am completely baffled. It should be working but these $loanAmount, $interestRate, $durationYears, variables keep showing up as NULL...

try:data: { loanAmount: loanAmount,interestRate: interestRate, loanTerm: loanTerm},

@Death-is-the-real-truth nothing changed. still NULL

getPost() will pull the data from $_POST, according to CI documentation - but PHP does not populate $_POST in the first place, when you send JSON. If you want to access POSTed JSON data, you need to use $request->getJSON(), or $request->getJsonVar(...) if you want to access a particular item in the JSON directly. https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/incoming/incomingrequest.html#getting-json-data

@ubqty Sorry, remove contentType: 'application/json', and then use my first comment code and check

@CBroe how can i use $this->request->getPost() still? what do i change in my view code?

@Death-is-the-real-truth it worked! removing contenttype application json worked! why did it work? is it because the datra being sent is not json? tysm again

As said, $this->request->getPost() simply gets its data from PHP's own $_POST. And when you read up on that, https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php, you'll find: "An associative array of variables passed to the current script via the HTTP POST method when using application/x-www-form-urlencoded or multipart/form-data as the HTTP Content-Type in the request." - you did not send any of those two Content-Types, and so $_POST will not be populated by PHP to begin with.

data: JSON.stringify({
loanAmount: loanAmount,
interestRate: interestRate,
loanTerm: loanTerm
})
